# How to re-initialize Image View container with the original size of the image, in LaunchScreen?

Tags: xcode

In XCode, I'm trying to find a way to re-initialize an **Image View** container to match with the original size of the image, without entering size (width/height) manually? Is there any button or something to do it quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found how to do that. Select the **Image View**, then click on the triangle symbol on bottom right to deploy a menu then click on *Update Frames*.

[image]